# We need to vote more

Tags: discussion

I found a really good reading here, https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/264/14220 .

From that article;

> the graduation date of a site will depend heavily on having enough
>   users with sufficient reputation to properly lead and govern the site.

and

> From what I've heard talking to mods on other sites, the sites that
>   have gone on to launch averaged about 200 upvotes/day during the beta
>   period

According to [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all) page, our all times average votes per day is 94.4. Which is less than half of 200.

Comment: Voting improves the economy :)

Comment: I still see good number of active users, but no voting! **most** of the answers I see that are really nice and good end up with only 5 votes.

Answer (score 5):

I thought about this before, but found out that it's not true, we shouldn't try to vote what doesn't deserve voting.

Graduating the site means basically that the site have a good group of core users who understand the community specifications and can hold the important rules after the site graduates (in our case, the most important rules are authenticity and citation). So after graduation the site will not turn into a mess.

I think we should just act as normal, vote what deserves voting (both up and down), if that was sufficient to the site to graduate, then great! if not, then the site still needs a period of time to reach the limitations needed to graduate.

**Trying to "Cheat the system" is not a good idea**, maybe it will help graduating the site early, but it really might end up with ruining the site with spam questions and answers if the community wasn't as wise as it should be. We should wait until the community is really good and grown, and then, probably without being aware of that, the site will automatically graduate.

I like to remind that the visit/day rate jumped to more than 700 and then dropped accidentally to about 400, this is because we were promoting the site and it's OK, but this is a live example that such "campaigns" will not be good on the long run.

Comment: I wasn't trying to say we should vote what doesn't deserve voting. I was just trying to emphasize how important voting is and we should exercise it as much as possible. It is not cheating the system, it is using our rights to vote to its full extent.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that not everyone thinks to vote. It's okay to remind the community to participate by upvoting good content and downvoting the bad. This applies just as much to questions as it does answers.

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR:** There's no shortcut to this. We need organic voting -- people vote on questions and answers that are good. Invite others to the site.

If you want to increase your voting, I suggest you log in daily and check the [newest questions link](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) on the home page, and vote on whatever is new.

---

I just want to remind people that **voting needs to be done responsibly, or it can be very dangerous.** Voting is the foundation of SE; it raises and lowers reputation, which is mostly related to abilities and privileges on the site.

Also, SE has some mechanisms in place that relate to false (and seemingly-false) voting patterns, voting rings (people who just vote for each other), socks (fake users who exist to vote up other users), and other farces. **You may trigger some security mechanisms inadvertently,** and I'm not sure what the ramifications will be. Already, we're seeing some users have lost seemingly ill-gained reputation (like someone voting on 5-10 of their questions/answers within a minute or two -- favoritism).

I suggest we follow my TLDR recommendation: try to look at everything (at least every question) and vote on it. People seem to be voting on answers already, so I think we just need more (people and questions/answers).